# how to hide delta value on number+delta indicator in plotly.js?

Tags: javascript, graph, plotly, plotly.js

I'm having a hard time figuring out is there is a way to hide delta's number value on a indicator chart and only show increasing and decreasing symbol?

I went through the documentation, but doesn't look like delta object has an option to hide the number value. I'm thinking perhaps there's a way to do it with d3-format? Documentation Link: https://plotly.com/javascript/reference/indicator/#indicator-delta-valueformat

Current Config:

```
[
    {
        "mode": "number+delta",
        "type": "indicator",
        "delta": {
            "position": "right",
            "reference": 0,
        },
        "value": 225,
        "number": {
            "prefix": "$",
            "valueformat": ",.2f"
        }
    }
]
```

Below is image of when I'm trying to achieve, any pointers are much appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Can you share some code to show what you have done and what could be done to solve this?

Comment: I've added my current plotly config to the question.

Comment: The delta comes with the symbol _and_ the value associated with it. That said, it's possible to search the DOM for the delta's <text> element and do something like `delta = delta.replace(/\d+/, '')`.

Comment: @EricLavault Thank you, that exactly what I ended up doing. I will post the solution below.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using REGEX to replace the delta value in the DOM.

```
   let chart = document.getElementById(id);
   let deltaElement = chart.getElementsByClassName("delta");
   deltaElement[0].textContent = deltaElement[0].textContent.replace(/\d+/, "");
```

Shout out to @EricLavault for pointing me in this direction.